# Hazelcast Multimap performance

Tags: python, hazelcast, multimap

I'm using Hazelcast Multimap client in Python. In my case, I have to update thousands of key-value at the same time. I tried to put multimap value in the while loop but it took more time to update the values (around 30 - 40 seconds to complete). How to improve performance of put data?

```py
multi_map = client.get_multi_map('test').blocking()
keys = list(range(1, 20000))
while(len(keys)>0):
    multi_map.put(keys.pop(),"Test Data")
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve that would be to use `put_all` method, but it is not implemented in the Python client yet. I have created an [issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-python-client/issues/528) for it, and we will try to have it in the future.

For now, you might achieve a better put performance by making non-blocking requests in batches.

```
multi_map = client.get_multi_map("test")  # get a non-blocking multimap

max_size = 256  # adjust the parallelism level according to your application
futures = []

for i in range(20000):
    if i % max_size == 0:
        while futures:
            # Clear the in-flight invocations
            futures.pop().result()

    future = multi_map.put(i, "Test Data")
    futures.append(future)
```